# Does spartacus 4X support Commerce Quotes?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Does Spartacus 4X support SAP Commerce Quotes ?
I am trying to bring the Commerce quotation feature in the Spartacus storefront. But I could see that it is still in the plan Road map of Saprtacus 2021.
Please let me know if there is an alternate available for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Commerce Quotes support in Spartacus is looking more likely for H1 2022. See "future outlook" in our public roadmap: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/spartacus-roadmap/#future-outlook---2022-or-later

Which roadmap has quotes for Sept? I assume it's outdated, will correct it.